# How to set input value of one html page by clicking element on another html page using jquery?

Tags: html, jquery

I have html page name try1.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="join1">Join1</div>
    <div id="join2">Join2</div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and another html page name try2.html

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div><input type="text" id="val"></div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I wanted to set the input value of try2.html with different value based on what I choose to click in try1.html using jquery(script.js) as below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#join1").click(function(){
        $("#val").val("Z1");
        $(location).attr("href", "try2.html");
    });
    $("#join2").click(function(){
        $("#val").val("Z2");
        $(location).attr("href", "try2.html");
    });
});
```

Is there any mistake I have made which causes the value to not change? Thank You...

Comment: If you're switching screens or routes you need to handle it in the URL params or get the data from the server or use `localstorage` or start looking at js frameworks like React, Vue etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use GET parameter.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#join1").click(function(){
    $(location).attr("href", "try2.html?q=Z1");
});
$("#join2").click(function(){
    $(location).attr("href", "try2.html?q=Z2");
    });
});
```

Also you can change your input name.

```
 <div><input name="q" type="text" id="val"></div>
```

Then you can get parameters.

```
const queryString = window.location.search;
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
const ourValue = urlParams.get('q');
console.log(ourValue); //you can change your input value to ourValue.
document.getElementById('val').value = ourValue;
```